# How to get an insights summary in a QLIK SENSE chart that talks about factors impacting the trend of the chart

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I am new in Qlik Sense. We are trying to build a trend chart that shows the revenue trend against time series. We want to have a insights summary/ text commentary auto-generated along with the chart that talks about the major factors impacting the trend.
Can we achieve this using Qlik Sense insights advisor or any other feature. Any suggestions and help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Amrita

We were trying to use the insights Advisor for achieving this goal. Did not find the appropriate result

Answer (score 0):

In both the cloud and latest on-prem version of Qlik Sense, there is the new [NL Insights object](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Visualizations/DashboardBundle/Insights.htm) available in the Qlik Dashboard bundle:

[image: Screenshot of the new NL Insights object in the assets pane in Qlik Sense]

It will auto-generate natural language insights based on provided dimensions and measures in your app. Here's an example using a sample dashboard (the NL Insights object is on the right side of the sheet):

[image: Screenshot of the new NL Insights object in a Qlik Sense dashboard]

If for some reason the NL Insights object isn't available to you or doesn't meet your needs, perhaps due to customizability, you could instead roll your own AI feature using an [Advanced Analytics data connection](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/LoadData/load-data-from-advanced-analytic-connections.htm). In the on-prem version, this just be called an [Analytic connection](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-admin/May2023/Subsystems/DeployAdministerQSE/Content/Sense_DeployAdminister/QSEoW/Administer_QSEoW/Managing_QSEoW/analytic-connections-overview.htm) which you would set up with a [Server-Side Extension (SSE)](https://community.qlik.com/t5/Official-Support-Articles/Qlik-Server-Side-Extension-SSE-with-Analytic-Connections/ta-p/1715066).

The idea there would be to use a tool like Qlik AutoML, Azure ML, or Amazon Sage to train and generate the underlying NL model and then you can integrate that with Qlik, either loaded into the data model via Data Load Editor or loaded on-the-fly as users make selections by using [chart expressions](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/LoadData/sse-syntax.htm).

You could also make use of the [new OpenAI connector](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/LoadData/ac-openai-overview.htm) in the cloud version of Qlik Sense to integrate with their tech.